# Can someone please tell whats wrong with this c++ code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex{
    private:
        int a,b;
    public:
        void set_data(int x,int y){
            a=x,b=y;
        }
        void show_data(){
            cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
        }
};
   
Complex add(Complex c, Complex d){
    Complex temp;
    int a = c.a+c.b;
    int b = d.a+d.b;
    temp.set_data(a,b);
    return temp;
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1,c2,c3;
    c1.set_data(2,3);
    c2.set_data(4,5);
   c3 = add(c1,c2);
   c3.show_data();
   return 0;
}
```

> **want to know why add function is not wrking where as if i write c1.add(c2) and define function inside class then it works completely fine**

Comment: The call `c1.add(c2)` is impossible with the code you've written. There's quite a bit more wrong with your code than the current (as of this writing) answers are giving you. Probably because you're getting content from someone that still treats C++ like C. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

"a" and "b" are declared as private. You cannot access it from outside the class. You need to make it public or provide getters or move it to inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, the member variables "a" and "b" are private and therefore can't be accessed from outside the class. Also, mind that your "add" function may not be mathematically correct. If you mean to add two complex numbers you probably want to write:

int a = c.a + d.a;

int b = c.b + d.b;

where I assume "a" is the real part and "b" the imaginary part

Answer (score 0):

1. As the class variables "a" and "b" are private, you need to write getter functions for them. Sample code as follows:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> class Complex{
>     private:
>         int a,b;
>     public:
>         void set_data(int x,int y){
>             a=x,b=y;
>         }
>         void show_data(){
>             cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
>         }
>         int getA(){
>             return a;
>         }
>         int getB(){
>             return b;
>         }
> };
>    
> Complex add(Complex c, Complex d){
>     Complex temp;
>     int a = c.getA()+c.getB();
>     int b = d.getA()+d.getB();
>     temp.set_data(a,b);
>     return temp;
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     Complex c1,c2,c3;
>     c1.set_data(2,3);
>     c2.set_data(4,5);
>     c3 = add(c1,c2);
>     c3.show_data();
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

2. Or make the variables public to directly access from anywhere. Sample as follows:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> class Complex{
>     public:
>         int a,b;
>     public:
>         void set_data(int x,int y){
>             a=x,b=y;
>         }
>         void show_data(){
>             cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
>         }
> };
>    
> Complex add(Complex c, Complex d){
>     Complex temp;
>     int a = c.a+c.b;
>     int b = d.a+d.b;
>     temp.set_data(a,b);
>     return temp;
> };
>
> int main()
> {
>     Complex c1,c2,c3;
>     c1.set_data(2,3);
>     c2.set_data(4,5);
>    c3 = add(c1,c2);
>    c3.show_data();
>    return 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So, there's a lot to discuss here and it's a bit tough because it's hard to know what you're allowed to use. I've tried to remove that notion from my courses, at least.

Your class lacks any constructors. Relying solely on a setter is poor practice. Constructors are the correct way to initialize an object, and they are more efficient than a default initialization + setter.

You overuse the comma operator for no real gains. It just muddies readability.

Your `add()` function attempted to access private data, that's a big no-no. It would defeat the purpose if any free function could access private data as it pleased. The reason implementing the function inside the class worked fine is because as a class member function, it has access to the private section. Either make it a class member funtion OR add getters for your data.

The following sample adds constructors, replaces functions with operator overloads where they fit, and made a few other "better" practice changes. It also includes functionality that is available in C++17.

*When I help with homework questions like this, my preference is to use a couple things that are likely to have not been discussed yet; it helps prevent copy/paste dishonesty. But I believe it still helps in seeing the logic play out.*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

class Complex {
 public:
  Complex() = default;
  Complex(int r, int i) : m_real(r), m_imaginary(i) {}
  auto get_data() const { return std::make_tuple(m_real, m_imaginary); }
  void set_data(int x, int y) {
    m_real = x;
    m_imaginary = y;
  }

 private:
  int m_real = 0;
  int m_imaginary = 0;
};

Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs) {
  auto [leftReal, leftImaginary] = lhs.get_data();  // C++17 feature
  auto [rightReal, rightImaginary] = rhs.get_data();
  return Complex(leftReal + rightReal, leftImaginary + rightImaginary);
}

// No newline printed here because no other Standard type does that
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, const Complex& obj) {
  auto [real, imaginary] = obj.get_data();
  // If you care about setw() interacting with your output, this intermediate
  // step matters
  std::string val =
      std::to_string(real) + " + " + std::to_string(imaginary) + "i";
  return sout << val;
}

int main() {
  Complex c1(2, 3);
  Complex c2(4, 5);
  Complex c3 = c1 + c2;

  std::cout << c3 << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```